# Помогите победить rbac

Tags: php, yii2

Пытаюсь подключить авторизацию путем RBAC шаблон advanced
вот common/config/main.php

```
'authManager' => [
            'class' => 'yii\rbac\DbManager',
            'defaultRoles' => [
                'user',
                'moderator',
                'admin',]
            ],
```

common/components/GroupRole

```
namespace app\components\rbac;
use Yii;
use yii\rbac\Rule;

class GroupRule extends Rule
{
    public $name = 'group';
    public function execute($user, $item, $params)
    {
        if (!Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
            $role = Yii::$app->user->identity->role;
            if  ($item->name === 'admin') {
                return $role === $item->name;
            } elseif ($item->name === 'moderator ') {
                return $role === $item->name || $role === 'admin';
            } elseif ($item->name === 'user') {
                return $role === $item->name || $role === 'admin' || $role === 'moderator';
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

console\controllers

```
namespace console\controllers;
use Yii;
use yii\console\Controller;
use app\components\rbac\GroupRule;
use yii\rbac\DbManager;
class RbacController extends Controller
{
    public function actionInit($id = null)
    {
        $auth = new DbManager;
        $auth->init();
         $auth->removeAll(); //удаляем старые данные
        $groupRule = new GroupRule();
        $auth->add($groupRule);
        $user = $auth->createRole('user');
        $user->description = 'User';
        $user->ruleName = $groupRule->name;
        $auth->add($user);
        $moderator = $auth->createRole(' moderator ');
        $moderator ->description = 'Moderator ';
        $moderator ->ruleName = $groupRule->name;
        $auth->add($moderator);
        $auth->addChild($moderator, $user);
        $admin = $auth->createRole('admin');
        $admin->description = 'Admin';
        $admin->ruleName = $groupRule->name;
        $auth->add($admin);
        $auth->addChild($admin, $moderator);        
    }
}
```

backend/controller/SiteController

```
public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            'access' => [
                'class' => AccessControl::className(),
                'rules' => [

                    [
                        'allow' => true,
                        'roles' => ['admin'],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            'verbs' => [
                'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
                'actions' => [
                    'logout' => ['post'],
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }
```

при входе в backend/wed выдает ошибку Rule not found: group

Comment: может поможет http://des1roer.blogspot.ru/2015/06/yii-2-rbac_29.html

Comment: а в консоли пишешь `rbac/init` ? или нет? а `rule` после манипуляций есть в базе?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский   name( group) data (O:29:"app\components\rbac\GroupRule":3{s:4:"name";s:5:"group";s:9:"createdAt";i‌​:1452803748;s:9:"updatedAt";i:1452803748;}) created_at 1452803748 updated_at 1452803748 rbac init проводил

Comment: @des1roer честно не помогло потому что не совсем понятно что это ?

Comment: @Sergalas Так такая строка генерируется в `rules.php` при использовании `phpManager` а не `DbManager`..... при `DbManager` в таблице должо было расположиться всё...... а еще странно, что при таком несовпадении расположения файлов и неймпейсов что-то сгенерировалось

Comment: @АлексейШиманский где и какие неймспейсы не совпадают? Често певый раз работаю с RBAC как в принципе и с yii 2 и что пишеться в phpManager и  DbManager пока не знаю. Я так понимаю что это все из за неймспейсов ?

Comment: @Sergalas Я пока не знаю из-за чего. вот это: `(O:29:"app\components\rbac\GroupRu` вы откуда взяли? У вас это сгенерировалось где-то и вы это видели? Если да - то где? в базе? А если не сгенерировалось - то откуда взяли строку)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34404/discussion-between-sergalas-and--).

Comment: @АлексейШиманский  в базе в таблице auth_rule столбец data да кстате я вчат так и не першел не знаю как

Comment: @Sergalas достаточно по ссылке перейти в чат))

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Подскажите пожалуйста, дословно, что там происходит в этом классе?  `common/components/GroupRole`

Comment: @АлексейШиманский так вопрос решенный уже

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Есть несколько недочетов. В сумме они и дают ошибку.

1. Это путаница с пространством имен (*и это скорее всего основная проблема*)

Вы располагаете `GroupRole` в `common/components/GroupRole`, но при этом пространство имен: `namespace app\components\rbac`.

В `console\controllers` соответственно при генерации берется не то пространство имен, которое заносится в `auth_rule->data`

2. Это, возможно, недобавление роли самому пользователю.

**По-первому пункту** я бы предложил как минимум сделать небольшую модификацию:
т.к. в какой-то момент времени, возможно, захотите использовать не `DbManager`, а `PhpManager`, то последовать стандартной практике и сделать под `rbac` отдельную папку: `common/components/rbac`. И там уже хранить как и `GroupRule`, так и в дальнейшем еще что-то.

В итоге класс `GroupRole` положить в папку `rbac`. Получится `common/components/rbac/GroupRule.php`

В файле `GroupRule` поменять *namespace* на `namespace common\components\rbac;`
В строке `$item->name === 'moderator '` убрать лишний пробел у модератора.

В классе `RbacController`  также поменять `use app\components\rbac\GroupRule;` на `use common\components\rbac\GroupRule;`

В строках `$moderator = $auth->createRole(' moderator '); $moderator ->description = 'Moderator ';` убрать лишние пробелы у модератора.

**Второй пункт**. При вызове `yii rbac/init` должно всё получится, но при этом если есть уже заведенный пользователь с `id`, допустим 1, и мы хотим ему сразу дать права админа, то нужно:

- В таблице `user` чтобы было поле `role`. В вашем случае `varchar`
- В класс `RbacController` добавить *namespace*  `use common\models\User;`
- В конце метода `init` добавить

> ```
> if ($id !== null) {
>     $auth->assign($admin, $id);
>     $myadmin = User::findIdentity($id);
>     $myadmin->role = $admin->name;
>     $myadmin->save();
> }
>
> echo 'DONE';
> ```

и вызвать `yii rbac/init 1` где 1 - id юзера. Мы его прикрепим в таблице `user_assignments` и сохраним ему роль в `user`

Чтобы привязывать в модели пользователей, после добавления или обновления присваиваем роль:

```
public function afterSave($insert, $changedAttributes) {
     parent::afterSave($insert, $changedAttributes);
     // установка роли пользователя
     $auth = Yii::$app->authManager;
     $name = $this->role ? $this->role : self::ROLE_USER;
     $role = $auth->getRole($name);
     if (!$insert) {
         $auth->revokeAll($this->id);
     }
     $auth->assign($role, $this->id);
 }
```

Comment: значит смотрите что сделал что было сделано до этого и что получилось 
1) за мейм спейс большое спасибо все поменял.
2) за модератора тоже спасобо хотя вы понимаете это не суть.

Comment: @Sergalas что-нибудь получилось? Могу полностью написать каждый класс с тем что где лежит и что в них. У себя проверял - работает.....пробелы у модератора и прочее это я уж так.. код ревью) а то потом начнутся с этим проблемы

Comment: Все работает спасибо единствено не подскажите как можно избавиться от того что при входе не тем пользователем вываливается ошибка An Error occurred while handling another error: что бы был ну или редирект или окно что то типа у вас нет прав для входа на эту страницу ?

Comment: ответ я все равно присвою но если поможите буду очень благадарен.

Comment: @Sergalas Это возможно вы что-то там перепривязывали и у вас корневая директория не стандартная. нужно либо сделать свой алиас типа `Yii::setAlias('mobile', dirname(dirname(DIR)) . '/mobile');` в  `\common\config\bootstrap.php` либо более детально разбираться что вы там делали)) Так же в котроллере должен быть `actions` ... `return [
            'error' => [
                'class' => 'yii\web\ErrorAction',
            ],
        ];`   а вообще при `rbac` не тот юзер не должен входить куда не надо) ..... но это как-то более подробно надо смотреть бы

Comment: @Sergalas Попробуйте проверять права юзера на указанном маршрукте, и если нет таких прав - редирект... что-то типа: `if(!$this->cheсkByRule($action, $user, $request)) {
 if(!$this->checkPermission($route)) {
            Yii::$app->response->redirect('/site/error');
}
    }`

Comment: Алексей я здесь присваиваю ответ спасибо но создал другой вот http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/483555/%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-an-error-occurred-while-handling-another-error-yii-2  помогите пожалуйста с ним разобраться.