# Ошибка An Error occurred while handling another error: Yii 2

Tags: yii2

При использовании RBAC вываливается такая ошибка

```
    An Error occurred while handling another error:
exception 'yii\web\ForbiddenHttpException' with message 'You are not allowed to perform this action.' in E:\serv\OpenServer\domains\advanced.lc\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\filters\AccessControl.php:151
Stack trace:
#0 E:\serv\OpenServer\domains\advanced.lc\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\filters\AccessControl.php(134): yii\filters\AccessControl->denyAccess(Object(yii\web\User))
#1 E:\serv\OpenServer\domains\advanced.lc\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\ActionFilter.php(71): yii\filters\AccessControl->beforeAction(Object(yii\web\ErrorAction))
#2 [internal function]: yii\base\ActionFilter->beforeFilter(Object(yii\base\ActionEvent))
#3 E:\serv\OpenServer\domains\advanced.lc\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Component.php(541): call_user_func(Array, Object(yii\base\ActionEvent))
#4 E:\serv\OpenServer\domains\advanced.lc\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Controller.php(263): yii\base\Component->trigger('beforeAction', Object(yii\base\ActionEvent))
#5 E:\serv\OpenServer\domains\advanced.lc\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\web\Controller.php(108): yii\base\Controller->beforeAction(Object(yii\web\ErrorAction))
#6 E:\serv\OpenServer\domains\advanced.lc\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Controller.php(149): yii\web\Controller->beforeAction(Object(yii\web\ErrorAction))
#7 E:\serv\OpenServer\domains\advanced.lc\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Module.php(455): yii\base\Controller->runAction('error', Array)
#8 E:\serv\OpenServer\domains\advanced.lc\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\web\ErrorHandler.php(85): yii\base\Module->runAction('site/error')
#9 E:\serv\OpenServer\domains\advanced.lc\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\ErrorHandler.php(109): yii\web\ErrorHandler->renderException(Object(yii\web\ForbiddenHttpException))
#10 [internal function]: yii\base\ErrorHandler->handleException(Object(yii\web\ForbiddenHttpException))
#11 {main}
Previous exception:
exception 'yii\web\ForbiddenHttpException' with message 'You are not allowed to perform this action.' in E:\serv\OpenServer\domains\advanced.lc\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\filters\AccessControl.php:151
Stack trace:
#0 E:\serv\OpenServer\domains\advanced.lc\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\filters\AccessControl.php(134): yii\filters\AccessControl->denyAccess(Object(yii\web\User))
#1 E:\serv\OpenServer\domains\advanced.lc\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\ActionFilter.php(71): yii\filters\AccessControl->beforeAction(Object(yii\base\InlineAction))
#2 [internal function]: yii\base\ActionFilter->beforeFilter(Object(yii\base\ActionEvent))
#3 E:\serv\OpenServer\domains\advanced.lc\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Component.php(541): call_user_func(Array, Object(yii\base\ActionEvent))
#4 E:\serv\OpenServer\domains\advanced.lc\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Controller.php(263): yii\base\Component->trigger('beforeAction', Object(yii\base\ActionEvent))
#5 E:\serv\OpenServer\domains\advanced.lc\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\web\Controller.php(108): yii\base\Controller->beforeAction(Object(yii\base\InlineAction))
#6 E:\serv\OpenServer\domains\advanced.lc\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Controller.php(149): yii\web\Controller->beforeAction(Object(yii\base\InlineAction))
#7 E:\serv\OpenServer\domains\advanced.lc\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Module.php(455): yii\base\Controller->runAction('', Array)
#8 E:\serv\OpenServer\domains\advanced.lc\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\web\Application.php(84): yii\base\Module->runAction('', Array)
#9 E:\serv\OpenServer\domains\advanced.lc\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Application.php(375): yii\web\Application->handleRequest(Object(yii\web\Request))
#10 E:\serv\OpenServer\domains\advanced.lc\backend\web\index.php(18): yii\base\Application->run()
#11 {main}
```

вот контролер

```
<?php
namespace backend\controllers;

use Yii;
use yii\filters\AccessControl;
use yii\web\Controller;
use common\models\LoginForm;
use yii\filters\VerbFilter;

/**
 * Site controller
 */
class SiteController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            'access' => [
                'class' => AccessControl::className(),
                'rules' => [

                    [
                        'allow' => true,
                        'roles' => ['admin'],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            'verbs' => [
                'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
                'actions' => [
                    'logout' => ['post'],
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function actions()
    {
        return [
            'error' => [
                'class' => 'yii\web\ErrorAction',
            ],
        ];
    }

    public function actionIndex()
    {
        return $this->render('index');
    }

    public function actionLogin()
    {
        if (!\Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
            return $this->goHome();
        }

        $model = new LoginForm();
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->login()) {
            return $this->goBack();
        } else {
            return $this->render('login', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
    }

    public function actionLogout()
    {
        Yii::$app->user->logout();

        return $this->goHome();
    }
}
```

common/config/bootstrap

```
<?php
Yii::setAlias('common', dirname(__DIR__));
Yii::setAlias('frontend', dirname(dirname(__DIR__)) . '/frontend');
Yii::setAlias('backend', dirname(dirname(__DIR__)) . '/backend');
Yii::setAlias('console', dirname(dirname(__DIR__)) . '/console');
```

из плагинов только adminLTE стоит

Comment: Ну в конфиге контроллера доступ до всех роутов разрешен только для роли admin - это так и должно быть и вы пробуете зайти юзером с этой ролью?

Comment: @kroder  а как сделать что то вроде таблички у вас нет прав и редирект на frontend

Comment: Нужно разрешать для всех, включая гостей, роуты error и login.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Скорее всего вам нужно что-то такое в behaviors:

```
[
    'actions' => ['login', 'error'],
    'allow' => true,
],
[
    'allow' => true,
    'roles' => ['admin'],
],
```

Comment: заходит в админку и пишет 403 ошибку но админка вся видна в принципе я понял как закрыть спасибо большое ответ принимаю

Comment: @Sergalas по идее не должна показываться вся админка..... или пробовать `If (Yii::$app->user->can('index'))` или проверить что не админ и перенаправить типа, если не админ то: `\Yii::$app->getResponse()->redirect(\Yii::$app->getUser()->loginUrl)`  может это поможет как идея http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/468788/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%83-%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-yii2/468801#468801